# Substitute object file path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, grids

I'm new to Inkscape and I'm currently creating a large grid figure for a scientific publication that contains several graphs (each one labelled by a letter).

I would like to create several identical grid figures with different data, but the identical layout and labels. The grid figures would practically look the same, except that the datapoints in the individual components of the grid would be different.

An easy way to do this would be to import the grid components as links (not embedded), then to duplicate the Inkscape file and to edit the file path Inkscape uses to find the linked images.

How do I change the file paths, or is there another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in the XML editor in Inkscape. Select the object, open the XML Editor (Ctrl+Shift+X) and edit the *xlink:href*.

Also note you don't even have to do this within Inkscape, since you can edit an SVG in any text editor.